# In C# 8 can I create a local function / method inside of a method?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```cs
    public bool ArrangeCardOrder(bool IsFirstToLast)
    {
       try
       {

           if (Settings.Mode.IsLearn() || Settings.Mode.IsQuiz() || (Settings.Mode.IsPractice() && Settings.Adp == false))

           {
                if (IsFirstToLast)
                    cIndex = cIndex == cIndexLast ? 0 : cIndex++;
                else
                    cIndex = cIndex == 0 ? cIndexLast : cIndex--;
                return true;
            }

            while (true)
            {
                if (IsFirstToLast)
                    cIndex = cIndex == cIndexLast ? 0 : cIndex++;
                else
                    cIndex = cIndex == 0 ? cIndexLast : cIndex--;

                var points = App.viewablePhrases[cIndex].Points;

                if (points == 0 || points == (int)rand.Next(points) + 1)
                    break;

            }
       }
    }
```

The block:

```
    if (IsFirstToLast)
        cIndex = cIndex == cIndexLast ? 0 : cIndex++;
    else
        cIndex = cIndex == 0 ? cIndexLast : cIndex--;
```

is repeated twice.

Is it possible to create a local function for this inside my method and call that?

Comment: question: did you try? if so, what happened? short answer, "yes, that should be possible"

Comment: Local functions are supported from C# 7, C# 8 introduced static local functions

Comment: Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)

Comment: As local functions are a feature that exists from C#7, the answer to "is this possible in C#8" is: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yes", basically

```cs
public bool ArrangeCardOrder(bool IsFirstToLast)
{
    void DoTheThing()
    {
        if (IsFirstToLast)
            cIndex = cIndex == cIndexLast ? 0 : cIndex++;
        else
            cIndex = cIndex == 0 ? cIndexLast : cIndex--;
    }
    try
    {

        if (/* snip for brevity*/)
        {
            DoTheThing();
            return true;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            DoTheThing();
            // ...
```